# How to serialize a Moose object, including nested Moose objects

Tags: json, perl, serialization, moose

Trying to build an elegant way to serialize a Moose object with nested Moose objects.  Example:

```
package Asset;
use Moose::Role;

has 'value' => (
  isa => 'Int'
);

has 'owner' => (
  isa => 'Person',
);

sub as_serializable {
...
}


package Car;
use Moose;

with 'Asset';  # role

has 'mileage' => (
  isa => 'Int',
);

has 'driver' => (    
  isa => 'Person',
);


package House;
use Moose;

with 'Asset';  # role

has 'bathrooms' => (
  isa => 'Int'
);



package Person;
use Moose;

has 'name' => (
  isa => 'Str',
);

has 'favorite_assets' => (    
  isa => 'ArrayRef[Asset]',  # and so on... and just to complicate things a bit...
  lazy => 1
);
```

What I'd like is some way to serialize, perhaps like this:

```
use JSON;
my $car = Car();
return JSON::encode_json( $car->as_serializable() );
```

Perhaps the `as_serializable()` method contains some set of parameters that specifies which attributes (and nested attributes) to expand, and perhaps there's some protection against circular expansion as I've implied in the `favorite_assets` attribute.

Before I embark upon rolling my own, does something like this already exist?  I have to believe someone somewhere has faced this exact challenge.  I've looked all over the Moose docs and done a few searches, but haven't found anything obvious, but then again I'm still a newb.

The use-case is to be able to quickly serialize and make complex Moose'ish objects available via an http web api, i.e. accessible from JavaScript running within a client-side web browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Storage

Comment: @simbabque, thanks, MooseX::Storage is nearly there. Unfortunately it implements the selection of which attributes to expand via Traits, whereas this use case (web api) probably needs to be able to select attributes dynamically to avoid unnecessarily large (and expensive-to-compute) output.

Comment: I don't think that exists open sourced. You could have a JSON schema and feed the objects through that to "throw away" the attributes you don't want. So you're not talking about serializing for restoring the whole object. That's important to note here. The serialization is non-reversible and the overall object cannot be deserialized (in most cases).

Comment: @simbabque, absolutely true -- the serialization is not intended to be reversible. "Throwing away" unwanted attributes still means potentially building computationally-expensive data. I'm thinking about rolling my own and perhaps open-sourcing. Non-ref values would always be built; for others, the selection of attributes to expand would be a list passed as method parameters, e.g., as_hashref( 'driver', 'owner', 'owner->favorite_assets' ).

Comment: I'm thinking a JSON schema could work. Your API has certain types of messages that you can map your objects to. That way your code does not need to know about the underlying structure of the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration & ideas!

Answer (score 2):

I decided to roll my own. I'm posting my code here for the benefit of others who might need a quick & easy solution.

For best results, add this within a role to your Moose class tree.

```
=item as_serializable - Converts self to serializable hashref

INPUT: $schema is a nested hashref of attributes to expand or suppress. 

This example expands the 'owner' and 'driver' attributes within Car, further expands the 'favorite_assets' attribute within Person, and suppresses mileage:

  my $car = Car();
  my $car_serializable = $car->as_serializable({
    owner => {},
    driver => {
      favorite_assets => {}
    },
    mileage => 0
  });

OUTPUT: $hashref

RULES:
1. All scalars are expanded by default, unless they're private (name starts with _)
2. DateTime's are stringified and treated as scalars.
3. HashRefs, ArrayRefs, and Moose objects are not expanded by default.
4. To expand a given attribute, set corresponding $schema node to {}, adding sub-attributes to expand as desired.
5. To suppress expansion/building a given attribute, set corresponding $schema node to 0.
6. HashRefs & ArrayRefs are all-or-none in $schema. No option to pick by specific hash-keys or array-elements.
7. Unless specifically suppressed, all attributes are built even if lazy.
8. Any attribute without a value is skipped.

=cut

sub as_serializable {
  my ( $self, $schema ) = @_;
  return $self->_serialize_value( $self, $schema || {} );
}

sub _serialize_value {
  my ( $self, $value, $schema ) = @_;

  # scalar
  if ( !ref($value) ) {
    return $value;
  }

  # DateTime as scalar
  if ( ref($value) eq 'DateTime' ) {
    return ''.$value;   #stringify
  }

  # hashref
  if ( ref($value) eq 'HASH' ) {
    my $h = {};
    foreach my $k (keys %{ $value }) {
      $h->{ $k } = $self->_serialize_value( $value->{$k}, $schema );
    }
    return $h;
  }

  # arrayref
  if ( ref($value) eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    return [ map { $self->_serialize_value($_, $schema) } @{ $value } ];
  }

  # Moose object
  if ( blessed($value) && $value->can('meta') ) {
    my $h = {};
    foreach my $attr ( $value->meta->get_all_attributes ) {
      my $name = $attr->name;
      if ( exists($schema->{ $name }) && !$schema->{ $name } ) {  # suppress expansion (including get_value) if $schema->{ $name } is false
        next;
      }

      my $attr_val = $attr->get_value( $value );  
      if ( !$attr->has_value( $value ) ) {   # suppress attributes with no value
        next;
      }

      if ( $schema->{ $name } || ( !($name =~ /^_/) && ( !ref($attr_val) || (ref($attr_val) eq 'DateTime') ) ) ) {   # expand non-private scalars + all attributes specified by $schema
        $h->{ $name } = $self->_serialize_value( $attr_val, $schema->{ $name } );
      }
    }

    return $h;
  }

  # if/as needed, add support for other reference types here...

  die "unsupported ref='" . ref($value) . "' required by schema";
}
```

Note I baked in my own way of serializing/stringifying DateTime, which is specific to the way I consistently build my DateTime objects. You may need to change this for your project.

Thanks to @simbabque for the constructive comments that led to this solution, and thanks to @nothingmuch for the separate assistance and final code review.